# WM 6.5 retrieving data from SQL Server 2008, DataSet contains Data (seen in XML), but no Rows/Values found

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-2008, windows-mobile

So as it said in the title, I have a problem retrieving data from an SQL Server in my WiFi-network on a mobile device running Windows Mobile 6.5.

Whenever I fill my DataSet, I don't get any errors. Next, I write my XML backup file on the device' disk. This XML file contains a schema and also the data (it actually does!).

Here's an excerpt of this XML file:

```
/* The way datatable values are presented in my xml backup file */
<Table> 
   <c0>value0</c0> 
   <c1>value1</c1> 
   <c2>value2</c2>
   <c3>value3</c3> 
   <c4>value4</c4> 
</Table>
<Table>
   ...
</Table>
...
```

So this is apparently working...
What is not, is if I now try to access data that this table should contain.
I am doing this in these two ways:

```
// 1 (in forms):
textBox1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["c2"].ToString();

// 2 (in testing log):
DataTable dt = ds.Tables["tablename"]; // ds is static class member DataSet
                                       // and definitely not null, but strongly 
                                       // named DataSet (tablenameDataSet.xsd type)
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                            sw.WriteLine(row[col]);
                        sw.WriteLine("".PadLeft(16, '='));
                    }
```

Now last but not least, my code to retrieve the data:

```
string connString = "Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=databasename;
                     User ID=user;Password=pw";
string sql = @"SELECT c0, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6
               FROM tablename
               ORDER BY c5";

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connString);
conn.Open();

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
ds = new tablenameDataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
```

Then I am writing XML, then log, then accessing data in forms.
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count is 0, whereas all 7 columns are found. So it is the right table. And data is only found in that XML backup file...

Thanks in advance!
- Daniel

Comment: Why even bother writing the data to XML, unless you need to access it offline? Why is your DataSet object static? What exactly is not working? All your post says is, "*What is not, is if I now try to access data that this table should contain.*", but it does not say what you are receiving. Lots of info, but no clear question or problem.

Comment: I am writing the data to XML because the device might crash or a session is cancelled and shall be continued later on (WiFi access is not always given). But I will use SQL Compact for that now. The question is: Why does the DataSet contain all my data when serializing it but not when I try to access it programmatically?
I've done a work around now by letting VS generating the DataSet and all Controllers out of the data sources. Now it's working... Still don't know where my error was.

Comment: I remember from a few years back there was talk about using [Occasionally Connected Datasets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488004%28v=vs.90%29), but it seemed it did not always sync as expected. This left Developer having to write their own Read/Write routines.

Comment: Thanks, that link seems definitely helpful, will check it!!